# getting error, while adding android platform for phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Today I started `phonegap`, as per documentation I am trying to setup my environment into my local machine.

In this process, I installed `android SDK` and set the environment variables in `bashrc` file.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME

ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Git/adt-bundle-linux/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME

ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS

ANDROID_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export ANDROID_TOOLS
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_TOOLS
export PATH

ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
export ANT_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

I switch to my working director and getting the following error after ran the `cordova platform add android`

```
Creating android project...

/home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-     
android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure you have a Java JDK (not just a JRE) installed.
at /home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:43:27
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:651:7)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
Error: /home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
@barrett:~/Git/phonegap/hellowPhonegap$
```

same command ran with "sudo" like `sudo cordova platform add android`, throwing the following error.

```
 /home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
at /home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:158:19
at _fulfilled (/home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
at /home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
at flush (/home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
Error: /home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Which command shall I use later. If one of it,what's the problem.

can anyone help me.

Comment: I'm having the same issue (but on windows). Got any luck?

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem let's do this `javac -version` then it show the available versions like

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

fallow that. 
I hope this is helps you.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem 
add this to your path. in windows i did like this `path=%path%;%android_home%/platform-tools`

Comment: I don't think OP is using windows from a brief look at the question, and I can also see that the path you suggest is already added to the path variable.

Comment: one more thing, i am in Persia when i make an app with different language(local lang, e.g تقویم) it create when i want to add platform it shows this error. but in same time when i create English name (e.g, calender) it creates and add every platforms

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to ANDROID_HOME like this

`export ANDROID_HOME='your path'`

after check the path like `echo $ANDROID_HOME`

Answer (score 0):

What happened to me was, that I had the openjr**e** installed, but javac is actually part of the openjd**k**. Hope this helps someone.